# Custom connector - Power Apps for RSS Feed that needs basic auth

Tags: power-automate, powerapp, rss

I have an RSS Feed that used basic auth. How can I use power apps to retrieve the rss feed.
I have tried to pass the username and password  like below but no luck in powerapps

https://username:password@sites/feed/rss.

Can I also configure a custom connector for this for RSS Feeds? If yes how to?

Thanks in advance if anyone done similar

Comment: Check and let me know if this [RSS connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/rss/) helps, related article: https://www.sharepointeurope.com/building-an-rss-reader-with-powerapps-and-the-rss-connector/

Comment: Thanks Ganesh if thats the connector from SharePoint Teams site or the one in power automate it doesn't work with basic auth

Comment: Check links in this documentation for creating a custom connector: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/custom-connectors/#start-the-tutorial